# Template reference variables *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

**item.component.html**

```
 <div class = "col text-center" *ngFor="let item of items">
 <p> item :{{item}} </p>
 <ion-input type="text" #input (ionFocus)="myFocusVar #input>

 </div>
 <ion-button type="submit" (click)="editInput()"></button>
```

**item.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'item',
templateUrl: './item.component.html'
})
export class DetailComponent {
@ViewChild('input') myInput ;

items =["item1","item2","item3"]

editInput(){
let key = "|"
let v = this.myInput

if (this.myFocusVar== true){v.value += key} }

}
else {console.log('false')}
```

I want to edit my Input with a button when it Has the focus on, for example, if I enter a word and click on the button, it should add "|" after the word I entered. I prefer to not put the button inside of the div, I want a single button for all.

**The problem :** If I focus the second input and I click the button, it will add "|" to the first input and not to the second, the same for the third input.

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem? or maybe a simple example to help me understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code generates multiple ion-input elements, you should probably use 'ViewChildren' and 'QueryList' rather than the singular 'ViewChild'.

```
 import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core'
```

I'm not sure if 'ion-input' is its own component. If it is, you can import it as well and query for it.

```
 import { IonInputComponent } from './wherever'
```

then to query:

```
 @ViewChildren(IonInputComponent) inputs: QueryList<IonInputComponent>;
```

You would not need individual template reference variables if you queried them like this. Then you should be able to access that list in ngAfterViewInit or later. If you need the list as an array, you can call

```
 this.inputs.toArray();
```

You should be able to read each of the component's properties. Although its unclear from your code what you are doing with (ionFocus) bc I think you may have a typo / missing quotation mark there.

EDIT - I'm not sure what you're (ionFocus) line is supposed to do, but if you're trying to set a variable specifying which of the inputs has been focused. You can just use index numbers.

```
  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
```

And then

```
 (ionFocus)="myFocusVar = i"
```

That way , when you focus one of the inputs, myFocusVar will change to its index. Then you can use that index to reference the correct input from your QueryList.

Comment: If i have a lot of 'ion-input' in my page How would I import the right input ??

Comment: Well i'm assuming they all use the same component, right? You should only need to import the component once, and when you query it, it will show you all the ion-inputs on the page.

Comment: Can you clarify your code?  I'm not sure what this line is supposed to do ...   (ionFocus)="myFocusVar  #input"   <  --- is it supposed to be "myFocusVar = #input"  ???

Comment: ionFocus show me if my input is selected or note it return true if it selected, #input is a local variable that i use to add an element  to a specific input ,it a reference of my input, i don't know if i can set a global variable that englobe all my elements  ,  , sorry if my code isn't clear but i choosed a simple example to illustrate my issue .

Comment: Yes, but each template reference variable needs to be unique. You are assigning the same one to each of the three inputs in your loop, so it is only working to access the first one.

Comment: yes this is what i want to do , because of ngFor i can't set different reference for my elements

Comment: Right, so you can use a QueryList to get a list of all of them, and then select the proper one some other way, easiest way going off of your example would be the index of the loop. You don't need template reference variables w/ that method